# SQL install script doesn't run in magento2

Tags: magento2, module

I have installed module in magento2 and want to add more field in module table,

So I have deleted the table and update the install script.

After this follow the below command successfully:

```
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But table is not created in the database.

Comment: You need to remove module from  `setup_module` table

Comment: I have got it and Solve it So now table is created, but thanks for your comments

Comment: try php -f  bin/magento setup:upgrade